# Python finding index in a array

Tags: python

I am trying to see if a company from a list of companies is in a line in a file.  If it is I utilize the index of that company to increment a variable in another array.  The following is my python code.  I keep getting the following error: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'index'.  I cannot figure out what is going wrong and think the error is the line that is surrounded by **.

```
companies={'white house black market', 'macy','nordstrom','filene','walmart'}
positives=[0 for x in xrange(len(companies))]
negatives=[0 for x in xrange(len(companies))]

for line in f:
    for company in companies:
        if company in line.lower():
            words=tokenize.word_tokenize(line)
            bag=bag_of_words(words)
            classif=classifier.classify(bag)
            if classif=='pos':
                **indice =companies.index(company)**
                positives[indice]+=1
            elif classif=='neg':
                **indice =companies.index(company)**
                negatives[indice]+=1
```

Comment: This is no valid Python code

Comment: it should be `companies=['white house black market', 'macy','nordstrom','filene','walmart']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
companies={'white house black market', 'macy','nordstrom','filene','walmart'}
```

Is a set. It has unique entries.

```
companies=['white house black market', 'macy','nordstrom','filene','walmart']
```

Is a list, and can multiple entries of the same value. It can also be indexed.

Answer (score 2):

```
companies={'white house black market', 'macy','nordstrom','filene','walmart'}
```

The above declaration is a `set`. And since a `set` has **no ordering**, you cannot get index of any elements from it.

```
>>> d = {2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> d
set([2, 3, 4, 5])  # It is a Set
```

---

So, to index an element, it should be declared as a `List`: -

```
companies=['white house black market', 'macy','nordstrom','filene','walmart']
```

Comment: ... don't `{}` represent dicts in python?

Comment: @johnthexiii.. Yeah they represent, but only when it is declared as `key-value` pair. Else it is a set. Try printing `companies` in interpreter. You will get that.

Comment: @johnthexiii.. I added example.

Answer (score 1):

companies is a set, and set has no order, so it can't use index(). You can change it to list:

```
companies=['white house black market', 'macy','nordstrom','filene','walmart']
```